# Why does the Bitmap in C# expand an image's file size when saving it?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I'm working on a project which requires manipulating images in different ways by modifying their pixel data array. Working with the Bitmap class in C# is pretty straightforward, but saving a Bitmap seems to have a strange behavior.

Even for an image that is not retouched in any way, its size increases upon saving it.

e.g. `source.png - 2MB` becomes `destination.png - 3MB`

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(@"SomePath\source.png");
        bitmap.Save(@"SomePath\destination.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pay attention to how you check and verify your created PNG image. Use programs like Paint.NET (not to be confused with Windows own Paint/Paintbrush) to verify that the actual pixel data is the same or not. Depending on how you view the images, the effect you observed might just be down to the source PNG not possessing any DPI information. And it could just so happen that the viewer you are using assumes default DPI values that are different from the default DPI values the Bitmap class assumes...

Comment: Some changes are quite normal but I doubt it grows by 50%. Look closer at the precise size of the files!

Comment: Note that PNG compression is not a fixed-function algorithm. PNG standard allows serveral differnt compression algorithms, with many compression algorithms being tweakable. However, tweaking the parameters of a compression algorithm to get the best compression result is anything but trivial, and at some point the effort of finding the best tweaks and the best "algorithm tuning" is simply too much for an anticipated little compression benefit. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) In the end it is the decision of the implementors of PNG compression schemes how far they want to go and how much blood, swear and effort they and their software are willing to spend on getting a somewhat better compression ratio. Simply put, some software compresses certain images better than other software, even if both use the same underlying compression algorithm. One is just better at knob-twiddling... ;-) (And some, like .NET's built-in PNG compressor, are just plain bad...)

Comment: @TaW Believe me, I am looking at their exact file sizes.

Comment: As a side note: Getting higher compression ratio usually also means higher computational costs. So there is also a tradeoff to be made between performance vs. compression ratio. This tradeoff developers make when implementing compression schemes can and will vary depending on the requirements of the anticipated majority of use cases for their software and what is considered the typical hardware (performance-wise) the software has to run on..

Comment: @TaW, while not the typical difference you might see on a regular basis, it can be quite possible. If you start with a source PNG that is extremely well compressed (for example with OptiPNG), .NET PNG compressor will look really bad in comparison. Of course it depends heavily on the actual picture content, but 2MB vs. 3MB is not an extreme difference when comparing an extremely well PNG compressed image vs. .NET PNG compressed image...

Comment: Also, talking in % is a bit misleading. It's not guaranteed it'll always add 50% more in size. e.g. I tested it on another image that went from `6.32MB` to `7.92MB`.

Comment: For @TaW and anybody else who want to experience themselves the difference between 2 MB vs. 3 MB, here is an OptiPNG compressed PNG: https://i.ibb.co/M8s2zJk/source.png (roughly 1.9MB; it's up until the image hoster will to take it off-line; and hopefully the image hoster will not start tampering with the image file) Try the code in the question yourself with this PNG file and see the miracle that is the .NET PNG compressor ;-P

Answer (score 2):

This sometimes happens if an original image was created in a 3rd party software which applied compression algorithm when saving the image. When you open this image as a bitmap object, the compression is "undone". And upon saving, C# does not apply the same compression algorithm which was applied by the 3rd party software causing a resulting image to expand in size.